# Wait till await/async returns in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am new to await/async in Jquery. When I am trying to use it in my js file, It is getting executed, but not as expected.

```
async updateProduct (product) {
    product.travelers.forEach((traveler, travelerOrder) => this.updateProductwithPassengerName(traveler) )
    return product
}


 async updateProductwithPassengerName (traveler) {
     const travelerId = traveler.profile_id;
     var body = await this.userServiceClient.request('/v2/users/' + travelerId  + '/info','GET')
     traveler.first_name = body.first_name
     traveler.last_name = body.last_name

     return traveler
   }


async request (path, method, body) {
    const options = {
      method: method,
      body: body,
      headers: this.headers(),
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    }
    const response = await fetch(this.relativeUrl(path), options)

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new HttpError('Technical error occured', response.status)
    }
    return response.json().catch(function () {
      throw new HttpError('No results found', response.status)
    })
  }
```

Those are the 3 functions. What is happening now is that

> traveler.first_name = body.first_name
>   traveler.last_name = body.last_name

these are not setting in synchronous manner( after

> var body = await this.userServiceClient.request('/v2/users/' +
>   travelerId  + '/info','GET')

. These are executing after a quiet a long time.

What I am doing here is that, for each traveler I am setting first_name and last_name. And updating the product object. Since this setting of values is happening after a long time, product object is getting updated later, by the time UI page renders. I want this setting values to happening before doing anything else in jquery.

Looking for help

Comment: `async function functionName() {...` or `const functionName = async() => {...` did you not get an error in console?

Comment: Nope. I tried that too. No luck

Comment: You open another connection to the server for every traveler of every product ....Thats quite inefficient? Can't you provide one API to server them?

Comment: This question seems unrelated to `jquery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `forEach` will not await the asynchronous result and so your first function returns a promise that immediately resolves, without waiting for the requests to finish.

Here is how to correct:

```
async updateProduct (product) {
    await Promise.all(product.travelers.map((traveler, travelerOrder) => this.updateProductwithPassengerName(traveler) ));
    return product
}
```

Or, if the backbone cannot deal with all these concurrent requests, then wait for each of them to complete before issuing the next:

```
async updateProduct (product) {
    for (let traveler of product.travelers) {
        await this.updateProductwithPassengerName(traveler);
    }
    return product
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when using asyn/await in JQuery or angularjs or nodejs, use promise. Promise will complete the process and then return either success or fail. Then only execute next steps.Go through below links and you will get idea.

1. [Modern Asynchronous JavaScript with Async and Await](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await/)
2. [async & await in Javascript](https://davidwalsh.name/async-await)

Comment: (1) `async/await` is not specifically related to jQuery, angular or nodejs. It is native JavaScript. (2) *"use promise"*: when using `async` you're already using promises. So what are you saying here? (3) *"Promise ... will return either success or fail"*: a promise does not return anything -- it is not a function. It may settle.

Comment: @trincot Sorry sir, I think you misunderstood what i said. To clear what i meant, i share two links along with that comment. I will point out each where our views differ: (1) I didn't specified asyn/await is only related to JQuery or angularjs or nodejs. I suggest a solution for his problem, how i get a solution for same problem.(2)As you said, I used promise to resolve the problem.(3)I didn't specified that Promise will return a value. It will return success or fail and execute next statements.

Comment: *"I suggest solution for this problem"*, *"I used promise to resolve the problem"*: I don't see any concrete solution proposed in your answer. Instead you are telling the OP to "use promise": but he already does. You *do* say that a promise "returns". It doesn't. "Return" is a word with a specific meaning in programming language like JavaScript. Also a promise does *not* execute anything. It is an object. Links can be helpful in an answer, but the essence of it should be present inside your answer (in case the links break, your answer should still have ... the answer).